# Como puedo conectarme a mi servidor vps en Ubuntu, si he cambiado su directorio añadiendo una carpeta nueva?

Tags: ubuntu, servidor, vps

Por desconocimiento, el otro dia cometi el error de cambiar en el directorio de mi servidor vps en Ubuntu. Añadí una carpeta nueva, y desde entonces no puedo conectarme con filezilla a dicho servidor...hay alguna manera de poder deshacer dicho error?.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué cambiaste y en dónde?

Comment: Añadí un directorio desde filezilla y creo que me lo añadió a la carpeta root del servidor